# VB: ListView not auto-creating scrollbar when too many items added?

Tags: vb.net, listview, scrollbar

I'm currently housing a `ListView` on a single form, and then adding buttons to this `ListView` via code-behind. Everything works wonderfully except the fact that when there are too many items added to the list it doesn't create a vertical scroll bar? I can simply add as many buttons as I want to it without it creating one? Here's the code that adds the button to the list:

```
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        Dim btnCount As Integer = -1
        Dim totalButtons As List(Of Button) = New List(Of Button)
        Dim mItems As ListView.ListViewItemCollection =
                New ListView.ListViewItemCollection(lstViewEditor)

        For x = 0 To 14
            'Create Button
            Dim button As Button = New Button
            button.Text = "0"
            button.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
            button.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
            button.Width = ((Me.lstViewEditor.Width - 10) / 15)
            button.Height = button.Width
            button.Location = New Point(x * (button.Width), 0)

            'If start
            If (Me.lstViewEditor.Controls.Count <= 14) Then
                button.Text = "2"
                button.BackColor = Color.Azure
            End If

            'Add To View
            'Me.Controls.Add(button)
            totalButtons.Add(button)

            btnCount = totalButtons.Count - 1
            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf totalButtonHandler
        Next
        lstViewEditor.Controls.AddRange(totalButtons.ToArray)
```

Any help will be much appreciated! I have indeed set `Scrollable = true`

Comment: I've since narrowed it to the fact that I'm adding Controls to the view instead of adding an Item to the collection. Trying to add buttons to the collection now to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I could answer my own question at this point. The Button (controls) being added to the `ListView` were not being added to the View's collection, but instead simply added directly to the control. This is where I was having difficulty. I'm assuming that only when the collection children for the view grows past a certain point you'll get scrollbars because I simply added a few things to the collection each time I added the a Button and it gave me the bars! Didn't like this solution so obviously simply used a `DataGridView` for simplicity because of the pre-build `ButtonColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a height for the ListView.

Comment: The title says TextView, but I assume you meant ListView.

Comment: I do indeed statically define the height in an earlier method. I've since narrowed it to the fact that I'm adding Controls to the view instead of adding an Item to the collection.

Comment: thank you, yes. I have since moved to a DataGridView to make my life much easier. Don't even need buttons with the cellClick functionality. Thanks for your attempt though, it's much appreciated.